# Double Values are not passing from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to pass 3 calculated values from Activity 1 to activity 2. Every time I see the result as 0.0 in Activity 2. Please help.

### Activity 1:

```
submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    try {
        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick
                    (View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, output.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("gyrerror", gyroerr);
                b.putDouble("compasserror", comperr);
                b.putDouble("deviation", dev);

                i.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

### Activity 2:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.output);


        TextView gyroerror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gyerr1);
        TextView comperror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comperr1);
        TextView deviation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dev1);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        double gyroerr =b.getDouble("gyroerr");
        double comperr= b.getDouble("comperr");
        double dev = b.getDouble("dev");

        gyroerror.setText(Double.toString(gyroerr));
        comperror.setText(Double.toString(comperr));
        deviation.setText(Double.toString(dev));
}}
```

### Stack trace:

```
02-24 09:38:49.775      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
02-24 09:38:49.785      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11349: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
02-24 09:38:49.785      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
02-24 09:38:49.785      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11355: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-24 09:38:49.805      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
02-24 09:38:49.805      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9043: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
02-24 09:38:49.825      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-24 09:38:49.825      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 366: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-24 09:38:49.835      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-24 09:38:49.835      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 388: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-24 09:38:50.015      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.427MB for 1127536-byte allocation
02-24 09:38:50.195      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.846MB for 2536936-byte allocation
02-24 09:38:55.756      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-24 09:38:56.015      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 293 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-24 09:41:38.537      997-997/com.example.supriyaraman.sample W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: Your keys "gyrerror", "gyroerr" are different.

Comment: double gyroerr =b.getDouble("gyrerror");
        double comperr= b.getDouble("compasserror");
        double dev = b.getDouble("deviation"); is this correct?

Comment: onNestedScrollAccepted = where is this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using different keys to put and to get your values:

Put:

```
b.putDouble("gyrerror", gyroerr);
```

Get:

```
double gyroerr =b.getDouble("gyroerr");
```

To avoid that, I recomend you to define static values for keys and use it to put/get extras, so typos won't affect:

```
final static String GYRO_ERROR = "gyroerr";
...
b.putDouble(GYRO_ERROR, gyroerr);
...
double gyroerr =b.getDouble(GYRO_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in your intent. Like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
i.put("gyrerror", gyroerr);
i.put("compasserror", comperr);
i.put("deviation", dev);

startActivity(i);
```

Then in your next class you have:
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

This gets the extras from your INTENT not bundle. So you need to say:

```
double d = b.getDouble("gyrerror");
```

This should work.